# Is it possible to set up Ubuntu 18.04 as a Domain Controller?

Tags: 18.04, server, samba, configuration

There are lots of tutorials on the web suggesting that this is possible.  I accomplished this on 16.04 and created a bash script that was used to take several first-boot 16.04 systems and configure as a DC.  Most of the tutorials out there are for 16.04 or earlier.  Those which actually purport to set up an 18.04 system start after the author clearly performed some initial configuration steps before documenting the steps in the tutorial.

The references to this process found on askubuntu date between 2011 and 2017.  Obviously, things have changed a lot, so these are minimally helpful if at all.  I succeeded on Xenial, partly thanks to these older (now completely out of date) discussions/tutorials.  I am failing today because something has changed in the environment, which is not accounted for in these older processes.

I've attempted to seek guidance from the people who have published the Bionic AD tutorials, but the vast majority don't have a comments/questions section or ignore them since they've likely moved on to newer projects.

The closest I have come to success still results in failure.  Upon attempting to provision the domain, it fails setting up self join

```
Setting up self join
set_nt_acl_no_snum: fset_nt_acl returned NT_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED.
ERROR(runtime): uncaught exception - (-1073741637, 'The request is not supported.')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 176, in _run
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/domain.py", line 474, in run
    nosync=ldap_backend_nosync, ldap_dryrun_mode=ldap_dryrun_mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 2175, in provision
    skip_sysvolacl=skip_sysvolacl)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1806, in provision_fill
    names.domaindn, lp, use_ntvfs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1593, in setsysvolacl
    service=SYSVOL_SERVICE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/ntacls.py", line 162, in setntacl
    smbd.set_nt_acl(file, security.SECINFO_OWNER | security.SECINFO_GROUP | security.SECINFO_DACL | security.SECINFO_SACL, sd, service=service)
```

I freely admit that I'm still learning.  I also accuse most geeks like me of being grossly incompetent at documenting their knowledge.  Too often, geeks just assume that the reader has the same experience at all things surrounding the topic being documented, so omit critical details which are paramount to crossing the line from "A" to "B."

A couple of things stand out right off the top:

Is Samba still using Python 2.7, or am I missing something to direct it to use 3.x?  Python 2.7 isn't even installed on the system until after Samba is installed. **Finally found via another source: Samba 4.10 and later use Python3.  Earlier versions (currently available in Ubuntu repos) still use Python 2.7**

ntacls.py, the script which is failing the self join is using the function samba.**samba3**.smbd.set_nt_acl function, but "apt install samba" installs samba version 4.7.6-Ubuntu.  Is the use of samba3 python code related to the previous question (solve the former and it'll solve the latter)?

Am I missing something in the drive mounting parameters?  tune2fs reports

```
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
```